# Using a Django url reference inside a plotly/Dash application

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I'd like to embedd an dash application in a django website.
On my application page I'm setting up a navigation bar in which I'd like to include links to other parts of my website.

I've tried the following, but I don't know how to refer the urls from within the dash application

```
html.Nav(
    html.Ul(
        [html.Li(
            html.A("The link to Home",href="{% url 'app_name:home'%}),
        ]
    ),
)
```

A link is properly shown, but when I click it the page is only refreshed.

In my appname.urls.py file I have the following :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]
```

and of course I have the appropriate `home.html` template

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-and-django/4587) on the plotly forum. You can either embed a Dash app in an `iframe` or try [this unofficial solution](https://community.plot.ly/t/embed-dash-plot-into-web-page/5337/3).